# Active admin install with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I am sure people are using both Rails 5 beta 3, Devise and ActiveAdmin in their app today. For me, with a virgin installation of Rails 5 beta 3, I am fighting a battle. I have managed to install devise:

```
gem "devise", :github => 'plataformatec/devise', :branch => 'master'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre2'
```

ActiveAdmin complains about:

> /Users/sylar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre2/lib/generators/active_admin/devise/devise_generator.rb:22:in `rescue in install_devise': You provided devise 4.0.0.rc2 but we need: ~> 3.2. If you don't want to use devise, run the generator with --skip-users. (ActiveAdmin::GeneratorError)

I just cant get it to install. What is the correct gem for ActiveAdmin?

[They also state to use Devise 4](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) but complains about devise 4.

Comment: try with gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this

```
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

Comment: Could be nice to point out that support for Rails 5 is only preliminary.

Comment: Run "bundle pack" and "bundle install --path vendor/cache" command if you are having "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run 'bundle install' first." error message.